# UITableViewCell animation accessoryview hides during selection

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've got a `UIImageView` that has an array of images that form a progress indicator as the accessory view in my `UITableViewCell`.

Problem is that when I select the cell the image disappears. In Reveal.app I can see that the accessory view is still there, but it's not shown.

I've tried setting both the animationImages and `highlightedAnimationImages` to the same set of images but no joy.

Is there anything obvious that this could be? I've read all the other SO articles on disappearing accessory views but nothing seems to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
[customCell setAccessoryView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PolicyIndicator_Up"]]];
```

You have to set the accessory view image in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
It will never be hide until you did something.
Hope it will be useful for you.